# In a metric space $(X,d)$, $\partial A=\emptyset\quad\forall A\subseteq X$. Is $(X,d)$ a discrete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a problem in my book, which asks me

> Prove that, in a discrete metric space $(X,d)$, $\partial
>  A=\emptyset\quad\forall A\subseteq X$. Prove that, $(X,d)$ is a
>   discrete metric space.

Then, the author asks - **Is the converse true?** i.e. If in a metric space $(X,d)$, $\partial A=\emptyset\quad\forall A\subseteq X$, then is $(X,d)$ a discrete metric space?
Can anybody help me in this regard? Thanks for your assistance in advance.
N.B. Here $\partial A$ denotes the set of all boundary points of $A$ i.e. set of all those points in $X$ which are not interior nor exterior point of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is not discrete, then there's non-closed subset $A$ of $X$. Take $x\in\overline A\setminus A$. Then $x\in\partial A$ and therefore $\partial A\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Jose Carlos Santos, If $(X,d)$ is not discrete metric space, then how to show, there will surely exist a non-closed subset?

Comment: How does the author define discrete metric space? It's not a tricky question. My answer is right or wrong depending on that.

Comment: @BiswarupSaha If all sets would be closed, all sets would be open too (being complements of closed sets), ergo $X$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: In my reading, a discrete metric space is a metric space whose topology is discrete. That would make this answer valid. On the other hand, if by discrete metric space one insists on e.g. $d(x, y) =1$ then it's clearly not true.

Comment: @Berci Exactly what I thought.